# How can I execute defined form validators from HTML before submitting?

Tags: python, jquery, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a defined form created using FlaskForm/WTForms where I also defined the validators of the same form. I would like to know how can I validate it using the validators already defined in my form before submitting it, for example, having one button to validate the form and then another to submit the form.

I'm assuming I need to find a way to execute form.validate() from the html when a button is clicked. My approach was to create a view to only execute `form.validate()` and call it when a button is clicked using jQuery. However, this is not working. And I'm assuming because the form object created in the "create" view and that is passed to the HTML is not the same as the form object created in the "_validate_form" view. But I don't know what other approaches to take. I would appreciate some ideas on how could I solve this problem.

This is my FlaskForm:

```html
class CreateTripForm(FlaskForm):
    truck = SelectField('Truck', widget=CustomSelect(), validators=[selection_required], validate_choice=False)
    origin = SelectField('Origin',
                         widget=CustomSelect(),
                         validators=[selection_required], validate_choice=False)
    material = SelectField('Material',
                           widget=CustomSelect(),
                           validators=[selection_required], validate_choice=False)
    destination = SelectField('Destination',
                              widget=CustomSelect(),
                              validators=[selection_required], validate_choice=False)
    sender_comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[validators.Length(max=150, message="Máximo 150 caracteres!")])

    submit = SubmitField('Confirm Trip')
```

This is my view when form.validate_on_submit():

```html
@trips_blueprint.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create():
    form = f.CreateTripForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        trip_dict = {
            'truck_id': form.truck.data,
            'material_name': form.material.data,
            'origin_name': form.origin.data,
            'destination_name': form.destination.data,
            'sender_username': current_user.username,
            'sender_comment': form.sender_comment.data
        }
        trip = Trip.create(**trip_dict)
        return redirect(url_for('trips.create'))
    return render_template('create_home.html', form=form)
```

This is my view to only validate form. Which is not working.

```html
@trips_blueprint.route('/_validate_form', methods=['POST'])
def _validate_form():
    print('In _validate_form!')
    form = f.CreateTripForm()
    if form.validate():
        return jsonify(True)
```

This is the jQuery script I'm using to try to validate the form:

```html
function validateForm(){
         $.post( "{{url_for('trips._validate_form') }}" );
     }

     $('#validation_button').click(function(){
         validateForm();
      });
```